# How to remote debug in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, ssh, pycharm

The issue I'm facing right now:

- I deploy Python code on a remote host via SSH
- the scripts are passed some arguments and must be ran by a specific user
- the PyCharm run/debug configuration that I create connects through SSH via a different user (can't connect with the user that actually runs the scripts)
- I want to remote debug this code via PyCharm...I managed to do all configuration, I just get permission errors.

Are there any ways on how I can run/debug the scripts as a specific user (like sudo su - user)?

I've read about specifying some Python Interpeter options in PyCharm's remote/debug configuration, but didn't manage to get a working solution.

Answer (score 10):

If you want an easy and more flexible way to get into the PyCharm debugger, rather than necessarily having a one-click "play" button in PyCharm, you can use the **debug server** functionality. I've used this in situations where running some Python code isn't as simple as running `python ...`.

See [the Remote debug with a Python Debug Server docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/remote-debugging.html#6) for more details, but here's a rough summary of how it works:

1. Upload & install remote debugging helper egg on your server (On OSX, these are found under `/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/debug-eggs`)
2. Setup remote debug server run configuration: click on the drop-down run configuration menu, select `Edit configurations...`, hit the `+` button, choose `Python remote debug`.

   - The details entered here (somewhat confusingly) tell the remote server running the Python script how to connect to your laptop's PyCharm instance.
   - set `Local host name` to your laptop's IP address
   - set `port` to any free port that you can use on your laptop (e.g. `8888`)
3. Now follow the remaining instructions in that dialog box: copy-paste the `import` and `pydevd.settrace(...)` statements into your code, specifically where you want your code to "hit a breakpoint". This is basically the PyCharm equivalent of `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. Make sure the changed code is sync'ed to your server.
4. Hit the bug button (next to play; this starts the PyCharm debug server), and run your Python script just like you'd normally do, under whatever user, environment etc. When the breakpoint is hit, PyCharm should drop into debug mode.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to set this up, however, at step 2) where i'm supposed to setup the remote server configuration - how do I do this if i connect to the remote node via an SSH tunnel? Long story short, what happens is that when i run the remote code using "python <script> <arguments>" nothing happens, and after a while the console prints out a "error: [Errno 111] Connection refused" error

Comment: I added a minor clarification to the answer's step 2. Basically, you need to make sure that the remote server can setup a TCP connection to your laptop. If you need to go through a jumphost, you could try to setup a "reverse tunnel", e.g. using `ssh -L5555:<laptop IP>:5555 user@<jumphost>...`, and then enter the jumphost's IP in step 2, and do steps 3 & 4 again. Then, your python script should connect to the jumphost, which should forward the traffic to your laptop. I haven't tried this, but I think it should work. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! This is really useful information, but it's not trivial to make it work in my current setup. Basically the problem is still step 2), since i'm behind the company's VPN i can't create a tunnel between the remote (a host in a cluster) and my laptop...ports would need to be opened and forwarded etc. This is the reason why i was trying to approach the problem from PyCharm towards the remote host, and the only issue left was getting the scripts to be executed by a specific user.

Comment: If someone is trying to create the TCP connection from remote server to your laptop, you can use ngrok tcp connection.

Answer (score 0):

I have this (finally) working with ssh RemoteForward open, like so:

```
ssh -R 5678:localhost:5678 user@<remotehost>
```

Then start the script in this ssh session. The python script host must connect to localhost:5678 and of course your local pycharm debugger must listen to 5678
(or whatever port you choose)