# How to do debugging with Vagrant virtual machines?

Tags: debugging, vagrant

Before I started, I want to make it clear that the 'debugging' here I mean is for programming debugging, while not vagrant itself debugging.

We all know, Vagrant is great to maintain a solid devlopment evnrionment among a team, and also tons of benefits from it as stated all over Vagrantup.com.

My question is: For instance of python programming, how can I keep using my favorite debugging tools coming along with Pycharm on Windows, but the python dependencies are installed in the Vagrant virtual machines?

I can easily do the deployment and testing with Vagrant command line, but I still can not get the point of how to enhance the developing stage, especially debugging on the development machine (Windows here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have quoted Python and PyCharm as the  language and IDE, I will build on the same example. PyCharm supports a feature called Remote Debugging, but this is available only on the professional edition of pycharm. Pycharm has [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/remote-debugging.html#6) on setting up of a remote debugger. I am quoting the answer from this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744587/how-to-remote-debug-in-pycharm). To consolidate the steps required

1. Upload & install remote debugging helper egg on the remote server that is to be debugged (vagrant machine)
2. Setup remote debug server run configuration: click on the drop-down run configuration menu, select Edit configurations, Click on the + button, choose Python remote debug.
3. set Local host name to your laptop's IP address, set port to any free port that you can use on your laptop (e.g. 8888)
4. Now follow the remaining instructions in that dialog box: copy-paste t`he import and pydevd.settrace(...)` statements into your code, specifically where you want your code to "hit a breakpoint". This is basically the PyCharm equivalent of `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. Make sure the changed code is sync'ed to your server.
5. Hit the bug button (next to play; this starts the PyCharm debug server), and run your Python script just like you'd normally do, under whatever user, environment etc. When the breakpoint is hit, PyCharm should drop into debug mode.